# Javascript trying to sort a mixed array numerically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array e.g.

```
arr = ["Joe1,345", "James,1002", "Bill,24"].
```

I need to order them by number descending but there could be a different amount of numbers on the end. I have tried a bubble sort:

```
function bubbleSort(a) {
    var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
    return a;
}
```

But that didn't work - does anyone know how to achieve this? I've looked at other people doing a similar thing but their answers seem to only have a constant letter in front.

Many Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Examples - use a function that splits on comma: `function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a.split(",")[1] - b.split(",")[1];
}`

Comment: What happens if there are two names with the same number: `['Joe,100', 'Ann,100']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with an appropriate callback for this task

```js
var arr = ["Joe1,345", "James,1002", "Bill,24"];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.split(','),
        bb = b.split(',');

    return bb[1] - aa[1];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: As you once pointed out to me, you don't actually need those unary `+` operators, as `-` coerces. (Not saying you should remove them. :-) )

Comment: We have `console.log` now, no need for `doc.write` anymore!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes, i was saying that.

Comment: i know the console, i was requesting a splitter for the small window for resizing.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yeah, for answers like this one I made [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279476/134069), which canon implemented very quickly; just waiting for SE to add a UI for it.